# Return the attribute id from the element that triggered the event

Tags: javascript

I have an element, this element calls the function calcTotal via the following code:

```
$('.pause').change(function(e) {
    window.alert("pause changed");
    calcTotal(e);
```

The code of calcTotal(e) is as follows:

```
function calcTotal(event)
{   alert('calcTotal called');
    var myId = event.currentTarget.attr('id');

    myId = myId.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

    var timeRegex = /^[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{2}$/;

    if($('#start'+myId).val().match(timeRegex) && $('#end'+myId).val().match(timeRegex) && $('#pause'+myId).val().match(timeRegex))
    {
        var minutes = 0;

        var n = $('#end'+myId).val().split(':');
        minutes = parseInt(n[0])*60 + parseInt(n[1]);

        var n = $('#start'+myId).val().split(':');
        minutes -= parseInt(n[0])*60 + parseInt(n[1]);

        var n = $('#pause'+myId).val().split(':');
        minutes -= parseInt(n[0])*60 + parseInt(n[1]);

        var hours = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        minutes = minutes % 60;
        alert(hours + ':' + minutes);
        $('#total' + myId).val(hours + ':' + minutes);
    }
    else
    {       
        $('#total' + myId).val('00:00');
    }

}
```

It doesn't work as I had exceptected and when I debug with firebug it says the following:

```
TypeError: event.currentTarget.attr is not a function
var myId = event.currentTarget.attr('id');
```

I would like to store the id of the element in myId.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`event.currentTarget` is not a jQuery object, it's a DOM node.

```
var myIf = event.currentTarget.id;
```

Answer (score 11):

`event.currentTarget` isn't a jQuery object, so `attr` is `undefined`.

You can fix by the following ways:

```
$(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
event.currentTarget.id;
```

Comment: Are you seriously creating an entire jQuery object just to get a property that's right there?

Comment: @Kolink I add it to explain why the error happens. Take a look my update.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the rest of your code works as intended, I'd suggest:

```
var myId = event.currentTarget.id;
```

Because it's a plain DOM node, not a jQuery object, the `attr()` method won't, and can't, work.

References:

- [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.currentTarget).
- [`Element.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.id).