# Javascript return id of the element that triggers the event

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom-events, mouseevent

I have a range of divs (projects) which have a display:none-ed overlay container inside of them, containing additional info.

If the mouse enters the outer div, that overlay container should receive another class making it visible. On mouse leaving the class should be removed.

I solved it using `onmouseover="setactive('DIV ID')"`, but it made the code look pretty messed up so I tried to switch to Eventlisteners. It won't work though and I can't figure out why.
This is my script so far:

```
// Init Eventlisteners for each container

        window.addEventListener("load", start, false);
        function start() {
            var project_containers = document.getElementsByClassName('content-project')
            for (var i = 0; i < project_containers.length; i++) {
                project_containers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", setactive(), false)
                project_containers[i].addEventListener("mouseout", setinactive(), false)
            }
        }



// If mouse is over container, add overlay_active class

        function setactive() {
            var container = document.getElementById(event.currentTarget);
            var overlay_class = container.getElementsByClassName("element-overlay")[0];
            if (!(overlay_class.className.match(/(?:^|\s)overlay_active(?!\S)/))) {
                overlay_class.className += " overlay_active";
            }
        }



// If mouse is outside the container again, remove overlay_active class

        function setinactive() {
            var container = document.getElementById(event.currentTarget);
            var overlay_class= container.getElementsByClassName("element-overlay")[0];
            if (overlay_class.className.match(/(?:^|\s)overlay_active(?!\S)/)) {
                overlay_class.className = overlay_class.className.replace(/(?:^|\s)overlay_active(?!\S)/g, '')
            }
        }
```

Comment: Try `event.currentTarget.id` - have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14223385/return-the-attribute-id-from-the-element-that-triggerd-the-event

Comment: I am using plain JavaScript, no jQuery...

Comment: You don't need jQuery - `event.currentTarget is not a jQuery object, it's a DOM node.`

Comment: also pass the event into the event handler - setactive(event) and don't call the function when you're adding it as a listener.

Comment: technically you don't even need the id you could just do - `event.currentTarget.getElementsByClassName()`. Have a look here as well - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.currentTarget?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fevent.currentTarget -

Comment: Try not to call the callback functions when you add the eventListeners i.e. project_containers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", setactive(), false) should be project_containers[i].addEventListener("mouseover", setactive, false) and the var container = document.getElementById(event.currentTarget); is wrong, you already have a reference to the element via the event.currentTarget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the id to set `container`, your functions could be like this:

```
function setinactive(e) {
    var container = e.currentTarget;
        //your code
    }
}
```

And then the call:

```
project_containers[i].addEventListener("mouseout", setinactive, false);
```

Comment: ^^ this is what I mean!

Comment: Why not simply use `this`? `var overlay_class = this.querySelector(".element-overlay");`

Comment: "this" is the element the listener was bound to, event.target or event.currentTarget is the DOM node that was moused over... there's a subtle and annoying difference. querySelector isn't as cross-browser friendly either. Also, it only returns one element, so you'd want querySelectorAll

Comment: @ChrisIPowell `e.currentTarget` and `this` refers to same element. And `querySelector` is more cross-browser than `getElementsByClassName`, also if you look at code snippet that OP provide, `querySelector` this is what he needs.

Comment: not always. "this" can be changed using .bind() e.currentTarget will always give consistent behaviour... all of which is I suspect beyond what the OP is worried about. There's no reason not to use e.currentTarget. If you want to make it neater you can assign it to a variable as Jonathan did.

Comment: Ha! That was it. Thank you so much! It's not easy to teach JS to yourself ;)

Comment: nope, and events and scoping are some of the least intuitive areas of JS!